# Swift: how to save UIImage as data in cache, retrieve it from url, then delete it?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiimage

I would like to be able to store a `Data` object (from a `UIImage`) in the cache directory, and be able to retrieve it and delete it if needed.
How can I do so?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel, there are third-party libraries available which does this exactly take a look at SDWebImage here https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

you can use this pod: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

- Kingfisher is a powerful, pure-Swift library for downloading and
  caching images from the web. It provides you a chance to use a
  pure-Swift way to work with remote images in your next app.